# Can't attach photos to tweets

Tags: twitter, motorola-droid-x2

I'm using the official Twitter app on my Droid X2. Whenever I select a photo from the gallery, it waits for a few seconds on the Edit Photo screen, then returns to the Compose screen without attaching the photo. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?